# Where does this blank page come from?

Tags: geometry, landscape

This LaTeX document should have one (or two, now I'm using `\lipsum`) pages of A4 portrait, followed by one in A4 landscape. However, there's a blank landscape page before the one with the content, and I don't know where it's coming from. What gives?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\title{Test Document with Wide Table}
\date{1st December 2020}
\author{TRiG}
\maketitle

\section*{This is a document}

\lipsum

\newgeometry{,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm,landscape}
\begin{landscape}

\subsection*{Column Details}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{| l | l l p{14cm} |}
\hline
A & Stock Code & Mandatory & Some text here \\
\hline
B & Supplier Code & Optional & This is long text. \\
\hline
C & Manufacturer Code & Optional & \\
\hline
D & Alternative Code & Optional & This is even longer text. \\
\hline
E & EAN Code & Optional & This is further text. \\
\hline
F & Product Name & Mandatory & \\
\hline
G & Brand Name & Mandatory & \\
\hline
H & Summary & Optional & This should be yet more text. \\
\hline
I & Spotlight & Optional & \\
\hline
J & Price & Mandatory & \\
\hline
K & Recommended Retail Price & Optional & \\
\hline
L & Cost Price & Optional &  \\
\hline
M & VAT Rate & Mandatory & \\
\hline
N & Description & Optional & \\
\hline
O & Specifications & Optional & \\
\hline
P & Display & Mandatory & Permitted values: Visible, Hidden, Blocked \\
\hline
Q & Available for Purchase & Mandatory & Permitted values: Yes, No \\
\hline
R & Link & Optional & This should be a full URL to a location with more product information (e.g., a YouTube video). \\
\hline
S--AB & Categories 1 to 10 & Optional & Category 1 is mandatory. \\
\hline
AC--AL & Images 1 to 10 & Optional & These are the names of associated image files, in order. \\
\hline
AM--AV & Files 1 to 10 & Optional & These are the names of associated PDF documents, in order. \\
\hline
AW & Stock Amount & Mandatory & The permitted values are any number (including zero, for ``out of stock''), or the letter ``U'' for ``stock not tracked (uncounted)''. \\
\hline
AX & Product Weight & Optional & \\
\hline
AY & Source Supplier & Optional & \\
\hline
AZ & Product Unique & Optional & Required if there's a Variant Name in the following column. \\
\hline
BA & Variant Name & Optional & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

It would be nice also to reduce the indent on the table, but that's a minor matter.

Comment: your tabular is too long. Add `\enlargethispage{5cm}` after \end{tabular}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is to large, that can be fit on one page, consequently it is push on the next one.

Beside considering @ulrike Fisher comment, you can set `newgeometry` accordingly:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\title{Test Document with Wide Table}
\date{1st December 2020}
\author{TRiG}
\maketitle

\section*{This is a document}

\lipsum*

\newgeometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1cm} % increase area of text
    \begin{landscape}
\subsection*{Column Details}
\vfil\centering%
\begin{tabular}{| l | l l p{14cm} |}
    \hline
A & Stock Code & Mandatory & Some text here \\
\hline
B & Supplier Code & Optional & This is long text. \\
\hline
C & Manufacturer Code & Optional & \\
\hline
D & Alternative Code & Optional & This is even longer text. \\
\hline
E & EAN Code & Optional & This is further text. \\
\hline
F & Product Name & Mandatory & \\
\hline
G & Brand Name & Mandatory & \\
\hline
H & Summary & Optional & This should be yet more text. \\
\hline
I & Spotlight & Optional & \\
\hline
J & Price & Mandatory & \\
\hline
K & Recommended Retail Price & Optional & \\
\hline
L & Cost Price & Optional &  \\
\hline
M & VAT Rate & Mandatory & \\
\hline
N & Description & Optional & \\
\hline
O & Specifications & Optional & \\
\hline
P & Display & Mandatory & Permitted values: Visible, Hidden, Blocked \\
\hline
Q & Available for Purchase & Mandatory & Permitted values: Yes, No \\
\hline
R & Link & Optional & This should be a full URL to a location with more product information (e.g., a YouTube video). \\
\hline
S--AB & Categories 1 to 10 & Optional & Category 1 is mandatory. \\
\hline
AC--AL & Images 1 to 10 & Optional & These are the names of associated image files, in order. \\
\hline
AM--AV & Files 1 to 10 & Optional & These are the names of associated PDF documents, in order. \\
\hline
AW & Stock Amount & Mandatory & The permitted values are any number (including zero, for ``out of stock''), or the letter ``U'' for ``stock not tracked (uncounted)''. \\
\hline
AX & Product Weight & Optional & \\
\hline
AY & Source Supplier & Optional & \\
\hline
AZ & Product Unique & Optional & Required if there's a Variant Name in the following column. \\
\hline
BA & Variant Name & Optional & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{landscape}
\restoregeometry % return to original page llayout
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Odd that an overlarge table would cause a blank page *before* the table, rather than after, but this solution works. Thank you.